# Pandas: interpreting linked boolean conditions without using a for loop

Tags: pandas, boolean, boolean-logic

I would like to **achieve** the following results in the column **stop** (based on columns price, limit and strength) without using a stupidly slow for loop.

**The difficulty:** the direction of the switch (False to True or True to False) of the first condition (price and limit) impact the interpretation of the remaining one (strength).

Here is a screenshot of the desired result with my comments and explanations:
[image]

Here is the code to replicate the above DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

# initialise data of lists.
data = {'price':[1,3,2,5,3,3,4,5,6,5,3],
        'limit':[1.2,3.3,2.1,4.5,3.5,3.8,3,4.5,6.3,4.5,3.5],
        'strength': [False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False, False],
        'stop': [True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True]}
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is there an error in your last row? 4 > 3.5 but you wrote price < limit

Comment: Corrected, many thanks for spotting that.

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve that ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried it for 15 minutes or so but I did not get much. pandas has a `shift` function which allows you to use a value from a previous row. But in your case you basically need to take all rows into account because it would be possible that the switch is forbidden for 5, 10 or even 100 rows and you need to now the stop value 6, 11 or 101 rows ago in this case. I do not see any other solution than a `for` loop for this. pandas is really strong when you can treat each row independently but here you depend on all previous rows.